# ios 15 prewarming causing appwillLaunch method when prewarm is done

Tags: ios, swift, ios-prewarming

We had an app in production which was reporting very high time to interact(tti) for ios 15 prewarm.

TTI = timewhenViewController is loaded - mainStartTime

mainStart time is measured inside AppDelegate.swift's willFinishLaunchingWithOptions method like this

```
mainStartTime = Date()
```

and when first view controller is loaded we measure tti as

```
tti = -(mainStartTime.timeIntervalSinceNow)
```

We observed that for prewarm scenarios mainStartTime was coming very early (approx 2 hours before user even launches the app).

I checked online but found no documentation.
Just wanted to know can it possibly happen that prewarm is calling willFinishLaunchingWithOptions method while prewarming the app.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is poor documentation about Prewarming:

> Prewarming executes an app’s launch sequence up until, but not including, when main() calls UIApplicationMain(*:*:*:*:). https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/responding_to_the_launch_of_your_app/about_the_app_launch_sequence#3894431

But prewarming can call both `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` from my tests on my iPhone 13 with iOS 15.0.

I’ve created a test app which logs all calls to a string array:

**main.swift**

```swift
var logMessages = [String]()

func addLogMessage(_ text: String) {
    let date = Date().formatted(date: .omitted, time: .standard)
    logMessages.append("\(date): \(text)")
}

autoreleasepool {
    addLogMessage("main.swift")
    UIApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv, nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self))
}
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        addLogMessage("AppDelegate.init")
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        addLogMessage("willFinishLaunchingWithOptions")
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        addLogMessage("didFinishLaunchingWithOptions")
        return true
    }

    func applicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable(_ application: UIApplication) {
        addLogMessage("applicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        addLogMessage("configurationForConnecting")
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }
    …
}
```

**SceneDelegate.swift**

```swift
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow? {
        didSet {
            addLogMessage("SceneDelegate.didSet window")
        }
    }

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        addLogMessage("SceneDelegate.willConnectTo")
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    }
    …
}
```

Then did the following:

1. Launch the app
2. Use it briefly
3. Force quit the app
4. Lock my device and leave it for ~30 minutes
5. Unlock the device
6. Launch the app again

My logs:

```
12:28:36 AM: main.swift
12:28:36 AM: AppDelegate.init
12:28:36 AM: willFinishLaunchingWithOptions
12:28:36 AM: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

12:58:15 AM: applicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable
12:58:15 AM: configurationForConnecting
12:58:15 AM: SceneDelegate.didSet window
12:58:15 AM: SceneDelegate.willConnectTo
12:58:15 AM: viewDidLoad
```

As you can see the system launched my app (prewarm) at 12:28:36 and held in background until my manual start at 12:58:15 and after gave access to protected data and loaded UI.

Answer (score 5):

Apple's documentation is incorrect, here is the behaviour observed on iOS 15:

`UIApplicationMain()` always runs, including during prewarming.

What happens after this depends on whether your app uses the `UIScene` life-cycle.

- For apps that do support scenes:

  - `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` may be called (doesn't always happen)
  - `scene:willConnectToSession:options:` is not called - in fact the `SceneDelegate` is not created until the app is opened.
- For apps that do not support scenes:

  - `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is not called.

Comment: Also see https://twitter.com/FelixOmni/status/1466140731324739592

> We also burned a TSI on this issue, and it was confirmed to us that despite the documentation, pre-warming _does_ call AppDelegate functions including didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. We were further told that "the jury is still out" on whether it's a bug or intended behavior. 